# Use pretrained weight for another smaller model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

Is it possible to possible to use a pretrained weight of a large model (for example ResNet151) and cut a part out of it to fit a custom, rather small model?

If it is the case, how can it be managed?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: what you want to do ? in terms of cutting? else you can reduce the model size and make it portable with tflite

Comment: On one hand I have the resnet151 weights. On the other I have a custom model for classificatio which I want to retrained based on a resnet151 weights, without loading the whole resnet151 model, just something for 15 mio parameters

Comment: Yes it is possible, it is a common practice known as "transfer learning". Object Detection networks are known to use those kind of techniques. Look out for code sample of networks like Faster RCNN or EfficientDet.

Comment: @Jürgen K., Yes, through transfer learning you can achieve. Currently tensorflow supports ResNet101, ResNet152 and ResNet50 architecture for Resnet models. To Instantiate these models you should use tf.keras.applications.resnet module. For more details please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet).Thanks!